# string literal not appeating in bolt visual scripting

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

[image]

Below was the expected
But i was not getting as shown in the first picture.
Is string literal remvove ..?

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your question doesn't seem to be about that language

Answer (score 0):

had to regenerate type mappings for bolt